# Automatically increasing textarea size

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have following function `autoheight()` in `jquery` , which automatically enlarges the `textbox` according the text we input,

```
  $(function(){ 

  $(".form-textarea").autoheight();

  });
```

My issue is when I reload the page using `jquery` & `ajax`, the function stops working and the text box stops increasing the size according to the text content. I mean it is related to event delegation, can anybody find a solution for this ?

Functioning html coding of text area

```
   <textarea style="overflow: hidden; height: 26.234px;" name="comment" class="form-textarea"></textarea>
```

Text area loaded through jquery /non-functioning

```
  <textarea name="comment"  class="form-textarea"></textarea>
```

> **Note** - it works fine, if we refresh the page through browser.

Comment: Does your Ajax load overwrite the textarea?  If it does then it will loose its previous events/code hooks.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks, can you please show a sample coding of that, I mean we can use body as parent for "form-textarea"

Comment: The code is little lengthy, can you suggest how can I post it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you actually overriding the affected `textarea` element during your AJAX call?

If that is the case, you will need to explicitly call the `autoheight()` function on the new element within the successful callback of your AJAX call (as the older one was replaced and is no longer in the DOM and your function doesn't know about the new element).

```
$.ajax({ 
      url: 'your-target-here',
  success: function(){
              // Update your content here (or that may already be done)

              // Reregister your autoheight function
              $(".form-textarea").autoheight();
           }
});
```

Comment: ,Thanks.. I have edited the post, can you please confirm that information is sufficient ?

Comment: Rion, awesome, the same thing what you suggested has been test already by me but was in wrong part, now it seems its worked :) I will re-verify it

Comment: Glad that you got it taken care of :)